# Ctrl C does not kill foreground process in Unix

Tags: shell, unix

I have the following code written in a script anmed test.csh to start a GUI based application in foreground in Solaris Unix. When I run the script and want to kill the GUI process using Keyboard Ctrl + C, the process is not getting terminated. If I open the GUI application directly from the terminal, I am able to kill the process using Ctrl + C. Can someone help me understand why am I not able to kill the process invoked from a script?

```
#! /usr/bin/csh
# some  script to set env variables
# GUI Process
cast
```

Then I execute the script using the following command. I am not able to terminate the vcast process using Ctrl + C command.

```
 source test.csh
```

Comment: I am not familiar with the 'cast' command - but can you kill it normally using SIGINT (Ctrl-C)? Some processes choose to ignore SIGINT

Answer (score 0):

If it is being launched into its own thread then the hangup request may not get to the application.  You could add a signal handler to cascade the hangup request or look at the process table to see what the process id is for the app and then kill it.  This could also be scripted very easily.

Answer (score 0):

You should better execute the script directly, instead of sourcing it.

1) first add `#!/bin/csh` at the beginning of your script,

2) set it as executable :

```
$ chmod u+x test.csh
```

3) execute it directly:

```
$ ./test.csh
```

you should be able to kill it. Anyway, consider that the problem may be related to some executable code that you are running within your script. Consider to try to debug your script by copy-pasting line after line in a terminal until you reach the point where it lags.

Another possible annoying issue can be an infinite `while` loop. Check for this kind of error too. Maybe you have a *while* loop that never gets the breaking point.

Regards